# Unused slots in the stepper Motor

Tags: motor, dc, stepper-motor, wire

The motor I am talking about has six wire slots of which two are unused and wires coming from the motor are restricted to four (4 to 4 jumper connecting wires are there to connect the motor ).So why are these two slots left unused? Does this means it's originally a  unipolar six wire motor ? The vendor told me it's a 4 wire Bipolar motor.How do I know why these two slots are left unused?

I have stepper motor from **Astrosyn**. I couldn't find the data sheet and sorry I cannot provide an image for the motor. So the specs on the motor are as follows :

- Astrosyn Stepper
- P/n 4K1-4054
- TYPE-17PM-J311-P1ST

MIEBEA CO.LTD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many motors that have six wires and can be either used as a bipolar motor or a unipolar motor, your motor is probably one of them.

[image]

There is a chance that these two points are actually dummy ones and not connected but you can easily check with an Ohm meter, if each one has a low resistance with eather of the two sides of the coil (the resistance will also be half of the total) then you can use it as a unipolar too.

Refer to this [How to figure out the internal wiring of a stepper motor using a meter and a battery](http://www.massmind.org/techref/io/stepper/wiresmeterbattery.htm)

---

The motor specs seems to be located [here](http://www.eminebea.com/content/html/en/hybrid_list/custom.shtml)

Your motor code leads to this [datasheet](http://www.eminebea.com/content/html/en/hybrid_list/pdf/17PM-J.pdf) that has a six wire pinout

There is also [this  datasheet](http://www.eminebea.com/content/html/en/hybrid_list/pdf/hybridall.pdf#page=6) in the same link, in page 6 there is a guide about the model number interpretation

[image]